# Filtering a Text column in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query:

```
string recordLevelKey = row.RecordLevelKey;
var newValueShort = (from afl in this.Context.AuditLog_FieldLevel
                     where
                         (afl.Auditlog_RecordLevel_K == recordLevelKey
                            && afl.FieldName.Trim().ToUpper() == "MYFUEKDNAME"
                            && afl.OldValue != afl.NewValue
                         )
                     select afl.NewValue).FirstOrDefault();
```

But it crashes saying cannot compare **Text**

The `OldValue` and `NewValue` columns are of type **(text, null).**

So how can I fix this?

Comment: and what type is `Auditlog_RecordLevel_L`?

Comment: Is that the exact text of the message from the exception it threw?

Comment: What's the C# type of those fields? `Text` is a SQL type.

Comment: text columns cannot be compared like that. If possible change the datatype in the underlying table to varchar(max). Also, text datatype will be removed from SQL Server in a future version according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187993.aspx